# create template and esign from our platform instead of login to docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign php api where i can create templates but signer not working also I need to update everything from my platform instead of login into docusign website like esign, display esign design & once the esign is completed it will send mail without docusign template with our own mail content.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide code or ask a question exactly. You want help creating a template using PHP. Here is some code:

```
    $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost($args['base_path']);
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);
    $api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
    $templates_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\TemplatesApi($api_client);
    $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\TemplatesApi\ListTemplatesOptions();
    $options->setSearchText($this->template_name);
    $results = $templates_api->listTemplates($args['account_id'], $options);
    $created_new_template = false;
    if ($results['result_set_size'] > 0) {
        $template_id = $results['envelope_templates'][0]['template_id'];
        $results_template_name = $results['envelope_templates'][0]['name'];
    } else {
        # Template not found -- so create it
        # Step 2 create the template
        $template_req_object = $this->make_template_req();
        $results = $templates_api->createTemplate($args['account_id'], $template_req_object);
        $template_id = $results['template_id'];
        $results_template_name = $results['name'];
        $created_new_template = true;
    }
```

https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/EG008CreateTemplate.php

Comment: Hi Inbar thanks for your response, I need eSign should be added in document. Please check my code.

Comment: \"recipients\":{
    \"signers\":[
      {
        \"email\":\"$recipient_email\",
        \"name\":\"$name\",
        \"recipientId\":\"1\",
        \"tabs\":{
          \"signHereTabs\":[
            {
              \"anchorString\":\"Signature:\",
              \"anchorXOffset\":\"1\",
              \"anchorYOffset\":\"0\",
              \"documentId\":\"1\",
              \"pageNumber\":\"1\",
              \"anchorUnits\":\"inches\"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]

Comment: you are saying you can't use the package? you want to call API directly? not sure I understand the issue.